# Várias function em um arquivo

Tags: php, funções

Tenho um projeto em `php` e, dentro desse projeto, tenho uma pasta chamada `Funções`. Dentro dessa pasta tenho vários arquivos de funções.

Tenho um arquivo chamado `Logado.php`, onde faço a autenticação do usuário e chamo as páginas para ser carregadas dentro dele.

Em cada arquivo que tenho no site, eu tenho que chamar o arquivo da função. Faço isso dessa forma:

```
include "Funcoes/Inverte_Data.php";
```

O que eu queria saber é, se eu colocar todas as minhas funções dentro de um único arquivo e chamar ele no `Logado.php`, deixaria o sistema lento?

Pois acho que ficaria muito mais prático, porque, uma vez que todas as funções estão no arquivo principal, eu vou poder só executar, assim:

```
inverteData($data);
```

O que me recomendam fazer?

Comment: Acredito que seja mais lento chamar vários arquivos distintos do que apenas um único. Se tem costume de chamar mais de um arquivo, acredito que seja melhor unir todas as funções em uma só.

Comment: Que tal você medir? Se não conseguir perceber diferença provavelmente não importa.

Comment: Já pensei nisso tempos atrás da seguinte forma: "se fosse assim, não seria melhor fazer os comentários em outro lugar, já que as linhas de comentário também irão aumentar o tamanho físico do arquivo e aumentar o peso do processamento do arquivo na aplicação?". Logo acho que mais vale um arquivão bem organizado por dentro.

Comment: Entendo, porém sempre que eu recarregar o sistema, `Logado.php` ele vai carregar todas as funções, mesmo as que não vai ser usada. Isso não vai deixar o sistema lento?

Comment: Carregada pra você significa que ela vai ser executada, mesmo não sendo chamada ? Por que "carregada" eu entendo como que ela foi importada para dentro do código para ser usada quando solicitada. Antes disso, ela fica lá bem quietinha e não incomoda ninguém.

Answer (score 3):

É interessante ter várias funções em um arquivo desde que elas tratem do mesmo "assunto".

Por exemplo, você tem funções para manipular data (*inverter*, *brParaSql*, *SqlParaBr*, etc), então pode criar um aquivo com a classe *DateUtil* e colocar estes métodos lá, mas esta classe não pode conter métodos que não tenham relação com data (ex. *inverterLetrasMaiusculas*) pois foge da responsabilidade da classe.
Estes métodos **podem** ser estatísticos, pois são métodos que servem para auxiliar e é desnecessário ter que instanciar um objeto.

Quanto a ter que fazer a inclusão de vários arquivos, não vejo problema, porque se fosse um, ninguém utilizaria framewoks pois possuem muitos arquivos. E para resolver o problema de ter que escrever um monte de require, de uma olhada na [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) a qual trata sobre autoload.